# MySQL query in 1 hour select

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I want to SELECT with 1 hour average of 1 minute data.

ex)

```
id |          time          | value
 1 |  2018-05-16 13:45:59   |   3
 1 |  2018-05-16 14:25:39   |   4
 1 |  2018-05-16 14:55:39   |   6
 1 |  2018-05-16 15:35:19   |   1
```

I want view

```
id |          time          | value
 1 |  2018-05-16 13:00:00   |   3
 1 |  2018-05-16 14:00:00   |   5
 1 |  2018-05-16 15:00:00   |   1
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- We can use [`Date_format()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function to convert a MySQL datetime to a different specified format.
- We can convert to a datetime string, upto Hour level only, using `%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00`.
- Now, we just need to `Group By` on this modified time value, and use [`Avg()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_avg) function calculate the average.

Try:

```
SELECT 
  id, 
  DATE_FORMAT(time, "%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00") AS hour_time
  AVG(value) 
FROM your_table 
GROUP BY id, hour_time
```

**Additional Details:**

- `%Y`     Year, numeric, four digits
- `%m`     Month, numeric (00..12)
- `%d`     Day of the month, numeric (00..31)
- `%H`     Hour (00..23)

A complete list of various available Format specifiers can be seen at: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Answer (score -1):

```
select id, 
       DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%M %d %Y %H:00:00") time, 
       avg(value) value 
from table 
group by DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%M %d %Y %H:00:00")
```